# Python Flask argument validation

Tags: python, json, flask

I am new to flask and I am facing some issues, I need to return two thing in my post function based on my input request. '200':description: Operation accepted, '400':description: Mandatory body parameters missing or have incorrect type.
So My code is below

```
def post(self):
    parser = reqparse.RequestParser(bundle_errors=True)

    parser.add_argument('identifier', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('fine', required=True)

    # Parse the arguments into an object
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args['identifier'] is None:
        return {'message': 'Mandatory body parameter missing or have incorrect type', 'data': args}, 400

    return {'message': 'operation accepted', 'data': args}, 200.
```

But I am not able to return 400 when there is no identifier in incoming request. Is there any issue with my syntax?

Comment: I suspect that args['identifier'] is not None, it probably always has a value (even if that value is something like ""). Can you check what that value is just before your 'if' stratement?

Comment: Hi, Thanks @Ben I was a noob in flask, after a lot of digging I found that I shouldn't be using reuired=true. So here it always raises error if the incoming request has no identifier;) Any way thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After digging a bit, I found that ***required=True*** should be removed. If i wanted to have my return value. Or else Reqparser would raise errors if the there is a attribute missing in the incoming request.